# network in kali linux on virtual box ,host is ubuntu 14.04 lts

Tags: networking, virtualbox, services, kali-linux

Trying to start network on Kali Linux in VirtualBox. I tried:

1. `nano NetworkManager.conf`
2. changed manged from false to true
3. after that for restarting, I typed

   ```
   service network-manager restart
   ```
4. it showed `network : unrecognized service`

   [image]

Comment: yaa connecting to internet

Comment: suggest me any solution to this